# Choosing type of icon in JOptionPane with method argument

Tags: java, swing, methods, arguments, joptionpane

I'm trying to not repeat the code as much as i can and i'm currently stuck on (what i presume to be) very simple problem, but i can't figure it out. I've looked through SO but i couldn't find a similar question so here i am.

```
public void displayPrompt(String promptMessage, ?????) { 
    
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, promptMessage, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    
}
```

This is the method i'm currently trying to figure out. What argument would i have to pass in place of `?????` to change the `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE` in to, let's say,`WARNING_MESSAGE` ?

The description for the `QUESTION_MESSAGE` tells me it's an integer:

> int javax.swing.JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE = 3 [0x3]
>
> QUESTION_MESSAGE
>
> public static final int QUESTION_MESSAGE

Does that mean i *actually* can pass an integer to manipulate it?

**Example:**

```
public void displayPrompt(String promptMessage, int i) { 

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, promptMessage, JOptionPane.i);
}
```

That would be the most logical explanation, however the issue is that eclipse doesn't let me do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your method to this:

```
public void displayPrompt(String promptMessage, int i) { 

JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, promptMessage, i);

}
```

and then call it like this:

```
displayPrompt("Text message for dialog", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Tested it works. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Both of your solutions work perfectly (they pretty much come down to the same solution) Thank you Sharp edge and @TNT

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in one of the static fields of `JOptionPane` to your method as an argument and use the value when calling `showInputDialog`.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, promptMessage, i);
```

When you're calling the method, you'd do something like this:

```
displayPrompt("prompt", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
// or
displayPrompt("prompt", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```